# custom filter in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp

I have included **B.JSP** in **A.JSP.**
In A.controller I have the following filter.

**A.jsp**

```
<body background="${abc}" ng-app="myApp" onload-directive
    ng-controller="myController"  ng-init="mySwitch=true" disable-keys>
       <div class="modal-body" style="height: 500px !important;overflow-y: auto !important;overflow-x: hidden !important;">
                        <jsp:include page="B.jsp"></jsp:include>
                        </div>
</body>
```

**Bcontroller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $compile, $timeout, $filter, $window, myService) {
// code

}); app.filter('isempty', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return isEmpty(input) ? '' : input;
    };

    function isEmpty(i) {
        return (i === 'null' || i === undefined);
    }
    });
```

When I try to execute **A.JSP** I am getting the [this error](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=isemptyFilterProvider%20%3C-%20isemptyFilter)

How can I avoid that error.

Comment: module and controller code

Comment: @Sajeetharan I didn't get you, I have posted my jsp and controller code

Comment: where have you declared app = angular.module and ng-controller etc

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

As the error description states in the documentation,

> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

You have to inject your filter into the controller ending with `Filter` suffix `isemptyFilter` like below,

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .filter('isEmpty', function() {
    return function(input) {
    console.log(input);
      return isEmpty(input) ? 'emptyfield' : input;
  };

  function isEmpty(i) {
    return (i === 'null' || i === undefined);
  }
  })
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', 'isEmptyFilter' , function($scope, isEmptyFilter) {
    $scope.greeting = 'null';
    $scope.greetingVal = isEmptyFilter($scope.greeting);
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
  <input ng-model="greeting" type="text"><br>
  {{greetingVal}}
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I din't used that  `isemptyFilter` anywhere in the page

Comment: Then try removing the filter code altogether and if the error persists check whether all the dependancies you have defined are correct, ex: `myService`. And also check in your templates that whether you are using this `isEmpty` filter anywhere.